# Excel COUNTIFS formula with name and date range

Tags: excel

Actualy, '>="&$C&1 is a date range. ex. Beginning date: 03/25/13 End date 05/10/13. Then A1:A33000 is the name of the person(s).

How do I add a formula with name and date range that if you already encounter this name, date formula will not count it anymore?

```
=+COUNTIFS(MasterData!$G$1:$G$33000,">="&$G$1,MasterData!$G$1:$G$33000,"<="&$G$2,MasterData!E$1:E$33000,"="&$A$7)
```

Where would I insert the name range value. (Name range is in cell A1:A33000)

Comment: not sure I understand your query. can you not add `,$A$1:$A$33000,"<>NAME"` to the current `countif`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count an array that is not in there then use `<>`:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$100,">=" & start_date, $A$1:$A$100,"<=" & end_date, 
   $B$1:$B$100,"<>" & person_name)
```